# Consulta Simples Nacional Optantes (por CNPJ) - C#

Tags: c#, captcha

Estou implementando em C# uma Consulta de Empresa Optante pelo Regime Tributário Simples Nacional através deste link http://www8.receita.fazenda.gov.br/SimplesNacional/Aplicacoes/ATBHE/ConsultaOptantes.app/ConsultarOpcao.aspx

Já possuo implementado uma outra consulta semelhante (busca os dados cadastrais do CNPJ informado) e tentei me basear na mesma estrutura de busca... porém quando implemento o POST na URL citada um erro 404 (não localizado) é retornado... 
Não conheço muito dos protocolos WEB então será que alguém poderia me ajudar?
Tenho problemas com o Cookie e também com o envio dos dados para consulta... Estou testando com uma URL da Receita que me retorna o CAPTCHA, mas devo ter problemas com isto também...

```
    public class ConsultaCNPJSimplesNacional
{

    //public static int c=0;
    private readonly CookieContainer _cookies = new CookieContainer();
    private const String urlBaseReceitaFederalCNPJ = "http://www8.receita.fazenda.gov.br/SimplesNacional/Aplicacoes/ATBHE/ConsultaOptantes.app/";
    //private const String paginaValidacaoCNPJ = "ConsultarOpcao.aspx";
    private const String paginaPrincipalCNPJ = "ConsultarOpcao.aspx";
    private const String paginaCaptchaCNPJ = "http://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/scripts/srf/intercepta/captcha.aspx?opt=image";


    public Bitmap GetCaptchaCNPJ()
    {
        String htmlResult;
        Bitmap retorno;

        using (var wc = new CookieAwareWebClient())
        {
            wc.SetCookieContainer(_cookies);
            wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Synapse)";
            wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.KeepAlive] = "300";
            htmlResult = wc.DownloadString(urlBaseReceitaFederalCNPJ + paginaPrincipalCNPJ);
        }
        if (htmlResult.Length > 0)
        {
            var wc2 = new CookieAwareWebClient();
            wc2.SetCookieContainer(_cookies);
            wc2.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Synapse)";
            wc2.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.KeepAlive] = "300";

            retorno = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(new System.IO.MemoryStream(wc2.DownloadData(paginaCaptchaCNPJ)));

            return retorno;

        }
        return null;
    }

    public String ConsultaCNPJ(string aCNPJ, string aCaptcha)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlBaseReceitaFederalCNPJ + paginaPrincipalCNPJ);
        request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
        request.CookieContainer = _cookies;
        request.Method = "POST";



        string postData = "";
        postData = string.Format("{0}__EVENTTARGET={1}&", postData, "null");
        postData = string.Format("{0}__EVENTARGUMENT={1}&", postData, "null");
        postData = string.Format("{0}__VIEWSTATE={1}&", postData, "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");
        postData = string.Format("{0}__EVENTVALIDATION={1}&", postData, "/wEWBgLq/eloAqye/fEBAubugugBArTc7JALAoj16KgKAsPCk6ABUmPOXmbrPKdGe79cSZ5xd7+tpvEhZPqniHtlSzKz9g0=");
        postData = string.Format("{0}ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderConteudo$635896812039632962={1}&", postData, new Regex(@"[^\d]").Replace(aCNPJ, string.Empty));
        postData = string.Format("{0}ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderConteudo$HiddenField1={1}&", postData, "635896812039632962");
        postData = string.Format("{0}ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderConteudo$hddServidorCaptcha={1}&", postData, "pro");
        postData = string.Format("{0}ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderConteudo$txtTexto_captcha_serpro_gov_br={1}&", postData, aCaptcha);
        postData = string.Format("{0}ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderConteudo$btnConfirmar={1}&", postData, "Consultar");


        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader stHtml = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"));
        String retorno = stHtml.ReadToEnd();

        if (retorno.Contains("Verifique se o mesmo foi digitado corretamente"))
            throw new System.InvalidOperationException("O número do CNPJ não foi digitado corretamente");
        if (retorno.Contains("Erro na Consulta"))
            throw new System.InvalidOperationException("Os caracteres digitados não correspondem com a imagem");
        if (retorno.Contains("Esta página tem como objetivo permitir"))
            throw new System.InvalidOperationException("Erro não mapeado...");

        return retorno;
    }
}
```

Alguém por ai já implementou ou pode me ajudar a implementar este tipo de Consulta?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depois de muito quebrar a cabeça e obter ajuda de um colega de profissão na área WEB eu consegui reformular os métodos e obter o resultado desejado...

Abaixo código detalhado e funcional...!
PS.: Estava falhando na hora de enviar os parametros e também na passagem do cookie contendo o TOKEN do Captcha...
Que sirva de exemplo pra outros muitos que precisaram e desistiram no meio do caminho...

```
public class ConsultaCNPJSimplesNacional
{
    private string viewState, eventValidation, hiddenField1, servidorCaptcha, stringCookies, token = string.Empty, img = string.Empty;

    private const String urlBaseReceitaFederalCNPJ = "http://www8.receita.fazenda.gov.br/SimplesNacional/Aplicacoes/ATBHE/ConsultaOptantes.app/ConsultarOpcao.aspx";
    private const String paginaCaptchaCNPJ = "http://www8.receita.fazenda.gov.br/SimplesNacional/Aplicacoes/ATBHE/ConsultaOptantes.app/Captcha/Inicializa.ashx";

    /// <summary>
    /// Captura Captcha e também armazena valores de alguns parametros a serem enviados na Consulta
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Retorna BITMAP contendo imagem Captcha</returns>
    public Bitmap GetCaptchaCNPJ()
    {
        String htmlResult = string.Empty;
        Bitmap retorno = null;

        try
        {
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();

            wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");

            //requisita valores das variaveis para armazenamento
            htmlResult = wc.DownloadString(urlBaseReceitaFederalCNPJ);

            if (htmlResult.Length > 0)
            {
                var doc = new HtmlDocument();
                doc.LoadHtml(htmlResult);


                servidorCaptcha = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("input")
                                .First(i => i.Attributes["id"] != null &&
                                            i.Attributes["id"].Value == "hddServidorCaptcha")
                                .Attributes["value"].Value;

                viewState = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("input")
                                .First(i => i.Attributes["id"] != null &&
                                            i.Attributes["id"].Value == "__VIEWSTATE")
                                .Attributes["value"].Value;

                eventValidation = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("input")
                                .First(i => i.Attributes["id"] != null &&
                                            i.Attributes["id"].Value == "__EVENTVALIDATION")
                                .Attributes["value"].Value;

                hiddenField1 = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("input")
                                .First(i => i.Attributes["id"] != null &&
                                            i.Attributes["id"].Value == "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderConteudo_HiddenField1")
                                .Attributes["value"].Value;

                //requisita Captcha armazenando TOKEN a ser utilizado na Consulta
                htmlResult = wc.DownloadString(paginaCaptchaCNPJ);

                if (htmlResult.Length > 0)
                {
                    stringCookies = htmlResult;

                    string[] x = Regex.Split(htmlResult, "\",\"");

                    foreach (string s in x)
                    {
                        if (s.IndexOf("Token") >= 0)
                            token = new Regex(@"[^\d]").Replace(s, string.Empty);
                        else if (s.IndexOf("Dados") >= 0)
                            img = s.Substring(8);
                    }

                    if (img.Length > 0)
                    {
                        byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(img);
                        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);

                        Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true, true);

                        retorno = (Bitmap)image;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }

        return retorno;

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Faz Consulta do CNPJ informado pelo Usuário, verificando se o mesmo é Optante pelo Simples Nacional
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="aCNPJ">CNPJ sem traços</param>
    /// <param name="aCaptcha">Conteúdo Captcha informado</param>
    /// <returns>Retorna Dados Cadastrais CNPJ e Regime Tributário Optado</returns>
    public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> ConsultaCNPJ(string aCNPJ, string aCaptcha)
    {
        try
        {
            using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Cookie] = "captcha_token=" + token;
                wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
                wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage] = "pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4";
                wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding] = "gzip, deflate";
                wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Host] = "www8.receita.fazenda.gov.br";
                wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.152 Safari/537.36";


                byte[] response =
                wc.UploadValues(urlBaseReceitaFederalCNPJ, new NameValueCollection()
                {
                    { "__EVENTTARGET", "null" }, //conteudo estático, sempre nulo
                    { "__EVENTARGUMENT", "null" }, //conteudo estático, sempre nulo
                    { "__VIEWSTATE", viewState }, //conteudo armazenado durante consulta Captcha
                    { "__EVENTVALIDATION", eventValidation },//conteudo armazenado durante consulta Captcha
                    { string.Format("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderConteudo${0}", hiddenField1), new Regex(@"[^\d]").Replace(aCNPJ, string.Empty) }, //identifica parametro CNPJ adicionando à propriedade NAME o conteudo dinâmico da varíavel armazenada durante captura Captcha
                    { "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderConteudo$HiddenField1", hiddenField1 }, //conteudo armazenado durante consulta Captcha
                    { "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderConteudo$hddServidorCaptcha", servidorCaptcha }, //conteudo armazenado durante consulta Captcha
                    { "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderConteudo$txtTexto_captcha_serpro_gov_br", aCaptcha }, //Captcha digitado
                    { "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderConteudo$btnConfirmar", "Consultar" } //conteúdo estático de consulta
                });

                string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);

                //trata e retorna valores encontrados
                return TratarRetorno(result);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Captura os dados de Retorno do Site da Receita Federal
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="resultado">STRING contendo Retorno da Consulta Realizada na Receita Federal</param>
    /// <returns>Retorna lista contendo Dados Cadastrais e Situação do CNPJ na Receita Federal</returns>
    private static List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> TratarRetorno(string resultado)
    {
        List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> retorno = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

        try
        {
            var doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(resultado);

            #region ... Validação CAPTCHA ERROR...
            var itemError = (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection)doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderConteudo_pnlConsulta']");

            if (itemError != null)
            {
                foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node in itemError)
                {
                    if (node.SelectNodes("//span[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderConteudo_lblErroCaptcha']") != null)
                        throw new Exception("Caracteres Captcha Inválidos.");
                }
            }
            #endregion

            #region ...Dados Empresa...
            var dadosEmpresa = (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection)doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderConteudo_Panel1']");

            if (dadosEmpresa != null)
            {
                foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node in dadosEmpresa)
                {
                    foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node2 in node.SelectNodes("//span[@id]"))
                    {
                        string attributeValue = node2.GetAttributeValue("id", "");
                        if (attributeValue == "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderConteudo_lblCNPJ")
                        {
                            retorno.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("CNPJ", node2.InnerText));
                        }
                        else if (attributeValue == "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderConteudo_lblNomeEmpresa")
                        {
                            retorno.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("EMPRESA", node2.InnerText));
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            #endregion

            #region ...Situação do CNPJ...
            var dadosRetorno = (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection)doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderConteudo_Panel2']");

            if (dadosRetorno != null)
            {
                foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node in dadosRetorno)
                {
                    foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node2 in node.SelectNodes("//span[@id]"))
                    {
                        string attributeValue = node2.GetAttributeValue("id", "");
                        if (attributeValue == "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderConteudo_lblSituacaoSimples")
                        {
                            retorno.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("SITUAÇÃO", node2.InnerText));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            #endregion
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }

        return retorno;
    }
}
```